# Ionic - Auto Select Checkblx

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

OK, this seems like it should be simple, but for the life of me, I cannot get these checkboxes to autoselect when the view loads. I am loading a client list and I already know what clients the user has access to.

I am using ionic3, angular 5 with angularfire2 against a Firebase DB. In the screenshot, you can see the value is true, but the checkbox is not selected on load.  I have tried ngOnInit, ionViewWillEnter, ionViewDidEnter

View:

```
    <ion-list>
        <ion-row *ngFor="let client of userAccessToClientRecords" >
            <ion-item-sliding  #item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-checkbox  name="clientItem" id="client.key" [checked]="client.checked" [(ngModel)]="client.checked" ></ion-checkbox>
                    <ion-label >{{client.clientName | uppercase}} {{client.checked}}</ion-label >
                </ion-item>
               <ion-item-options side="right">
                    <button ion-button (click)="gotoRigPage(client)">Set Rigs</button>
                </ion-item-options>
            </ion-item-sliding>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-list>
```

Typescript:

```
 this.user = this.navParams.data.user;
 this.clientsRecords = this.clientsService.getClientList2();

  this.clientsRecords.subscribe(items => {
      for (let c = 0; c < items.length; c++) {
        if (this.user.clientaccess && items[c].key && items[c].key in this.user.clientaccess) {
          items[c].checked = true
        }
      }
      this.userAccessToClientRecords = items;
  })
```

[image: Image Preview]

Answer (score 0):

Found out to use [ngModelOptions]="{standalong:true}" as it was sometimes setting them all selected as well.